# Expressing gemination in SPE

Tags: phonology, gemination, spe

Is there a way to express gemination in SPE notation? Is it common/correct to say things like

[+anterior] -> [+anterior][+anterior] / __ [+vowel] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kenstowicz 1994 (*Phonology in Generative Grammar*, e.g. p. 63) uses **±long**, just as for vowels, at least for the purposes of exposition. This is in line with the fact that the IPA length indicator **ː** is commonly encountered marking geminate consonants.